# In R:How do I itearate through character strings in a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, tm

I'm trying to access character strings from a vector in a for-loop.

I have a Corpus like this one:

```
library(tm)
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(c("cfilm,cgame,ccd","cd,film,cfilm")))
```

My goal is to get rid off all unnecessary "c" characters. Note, that this means I don't want to remove the c from cd, but ccd, cgame and so forth.

I use this function, which takes in a corpus and removes a term with a second one.

```
toString = content_transformer(function(x,from,to)gsub(from, to, x))
```

So, for example, to replace cgame with game, I use

```
corpus = tm_map(corpus,toString,"cgame","game")
```

Now, I instead of repeating this line for all the terms, I'd like to use a loop that iterates to all the possible replacements using a vector with the relevant terms.

```
replace = c("game","film","cd")
```

I tried two approaches, but none of them would work:

```
for(i in replace){tm_map(corpus,toString,paste("c",get(i),sep=""),get(i))}
```

and

```
for(i in 1:length(replace)){tm_map(corpus,toString,paste("c",replace[i],sep=""),replace[i])}
```

In the first case R tells me that it can't find the object received by get(i): `Error in get(i) : object 'game' not found`.
In the second, there is no error message, but nothing changes within the corpus.

How can I query items within a vector as strings, so the for-loop would repeat for all the terms, what I did with `corpus = tm_map(corpus,toString,"cgame","game)`

Comment: Please add from which package the function `Corpus` is. Note that the first line of code lacks of 3 parenthesis so please adjust it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tm_map` function doesn't modify the corpus in place, it returns a modified corpus. Right now you are not doing anything to save the result. Try

```
 for(i in 1:length(replace)){
     corpus <- tm_map(corpus,toString,paste("c",replace[i],sep=""),replace[i])
  }
```

Also, `toString` is actually the name of a function in base R so it's not a good idea to write your own function with the same name.

Finally, the `get()` method returns the value of an R variable with the same name as the character value you pass it. There is no reason to use `get()` here since you want to continue working with strings and not variable names.

Comment: I actually didn't notice I wasn't reassigning the result to the corpus. I feel dumb now -_- Works like a charm now. Thank you